# What is meant by C-rate and how to calculate current from it?

Tags: lithium-ion, automotive, batteries

[image: Cell Capacity]

I have been trying to figure out how to calculate the test current (It) for BEV application, the cell has a 6000mAh capacity. What would be the reference test current and the formula for it? Also, the charge current in the battery datasheet is 0.5 C, how would this work?

The attached photo is of the test standard I have to apply.

Answer (score 3):

The C rate is just numerically the battery capacity in Ah.

For this cell
1 C = 6 A
0.5 C = 3 A

The text you show is not all that user friendly, though it is strictly accurate, hence the notes.

3.3 note 1 - we ought to take account of the discharge time over which the battery capacity is rated. A fast discharged battery does return a lower total capacity. Some batteries are rated at a 20 hour discharge to be able to show a higher capacity figure. Having defined a C<sub>n</sub>, it's not clear from what you have quoted what value of n should be used to determine the rated current. The capacity can get much smaller as n goes to 1, perhaps half, or worse.

3.4 note 1 - the capacity is in Ah, and the current is in A. That's why the constant '1' has dimensions h, to convert one to the other correctly. I think it would have been better to use an algebraic constant like 'k', or better still 'h', which could then be defined as 1 hour, rather than '1', which looks to me a lot like 1. I handle that dimensional problem in my first paragraph by using the phrase 'numerically equals'.

Comment: So, according to the photo, n = 3 for BEV and It = Cn, It = 6000mAh / 3 = 2 A. It = 2 A, is this correct for the test current?

Comment: @TalhaAhmad No. It = Cn/1, Cn = 6, so It = 6

Comment: but n = 3 hrs defined for BEV in note 1, if I am not wrong, wouldn't that change statement change the current?

Comment: @TalhaAhmad Don't confuse the 'reference test current' It, and the current required to discharge the cell in 3 hours, which is 2 A. The capacity at the 3 hour rate is 6 Ah. The capacity at the test current will be somewhat less than 6 Ah (maybe 5 Ah, it might be in the data sheet), so the run time at the reference test current will be less than 1 hour, maybe 50 mins.

Answer (score 0):

The C-rate is just the current you are charging, or discharging into the battery that has been normalized to current that the battery can supply for one hour before dying*

The Amp-hour rating of a battery is the rating that tell you what level of current a battery can theoretically supply before dying. So if a battery is rated for 60 Amp-hours, it means that the battery should be able to supply:

- 60 Amps for one hour (C-rate = 1)
- 120 Amps for half an hour (C-rate = 2)
- 30 Amps for two hours (C-rate = 0.5)

Since it's normalized to battery capacity, it means that a C-rate always represents the same amount of time regardless of the battery capacity:

- C-rate = 1 always means 1 hour run time
- C-rate = 0.5 always means 2 hour run time
- C-rate = 2 always means 0.5 hour run time

*Theoretically because internal impedance will affect this number in usage and in measurement but let's ignore this details for now.

Comment: It's the same as the amount it can *ideally* supply for one hour but not necessarily the *actual* amount it can supply for one hour due to losses.

Comment: Is it though? In their terminology do we use C<sub>1</sub>, or C<sub>n</sub> whatever the latter happens to be?

Comment: I knew people would bring this up because they always do but it always just confuses people who don't even understand C-rating to begin with.

Comment: Mr Ahmad has brought that up in his original quote, so it needs to be addressed somehow.

Answer (score 0):

The ‘C’ rating of a battery indicates its capacity in ampere-hours (Ah).

‘C’ would be followed by a number (C10, C20 etc.) which indicates the number of hours the capacity would be distributed over.

For example, a battery having a C20 rating of 100 Ah would deliver a constant current of 100/20 = 5A for 20 hours, with its terminal voltage not going below the specified lower limit (end voltage).

This information would be available in battery data sheets, extending down to C0.5, C0.25 etc.

The following example data is for a lead-acid deep-cycle battery.

[image]

It is to be noted that battery capacity gets lowered for higher discharge currents.

The maximum load that a battery can power for a discharge period =  battery nominal voltage x discharge current.

The maximum load that the above example battery can power for 20 hours = 12 x 5 = 60 W.

The maximum load that the same battery can power for 1 hour = 12 x 65 = 780 W.

Comment: "The ‘C’ rating" ...

OP asked about "C-rate", not "C-rating". The first is a measure of actual current at a given time. The second is a marketing rating loosely based on the true engineering cell specifications.

Comment: Hi Davide, I find the words 'C-rate' and 'C-rating' being used interchangeably in battery data sheets. Here's an example - https://www.power-sonic.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/02/What-is-a-battery-C-rating.pdf